# Word for knowing something as a fact, but not fully comprehending its reality?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases

I'm thinking of the way a lot of people (myself included) remember information out of a history book:  You superficially understand that the information is true, but remembering it doesn't feel like understanding an actual part of reality, it feels like retaining an abstract piece of information.  Like you *know* it's real, but you don't *feel* that it's real.

I suppose it's generally the kind of extremely shallow awareness you have of something if you've been told about its existence, but haven't observed or experienced it yourself.

Comment: *disembodied history* is a fairly common idiom.

Comment: 'Dissociate' is a verb that might work here, depending on the context.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide a sample sentence.  People sometimes talk about events that they still need to "process"--they can't quite believe it or understand it--but that's not related to historical events, e.g., the Cold War.

Comment: sometimes people use the words "fuzzy understanding" or "fuzzy memory" ..as I , I know Pine trees are conifers but I have a fuzzy understanding of where the definition of 'conifer' differs from the definition of 'deciduous'.

Comment: You're talking about "book knowledge" or "abstract knowledge." For example, we are aware that the Franco-Prussian War and the Voyage of the Beagle happened, but we didn't observe or experience them ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for *is*

## [**know**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104157):

to have knowledge of, regardless of the level of understanding.

> To perceive... to recognize... to identify... to distinguish... to be able to recall...

**It's the *deeper* levels of understanding** that have other vocab words: [*understand*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/212085)

> To comprehend... to apprehend the meaning or import of... to grasp the idea of...

*[comprehend](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/37847)*

> To grasp with the mind... to conceive fully or adequately... to understand... to lay hold of all the points of ~ and include them within the compass of a description or expression...

*[appreciate](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/9787)*

> To apprehend or understand clearly or correctly... to recognize the significance or subtleties of...

*[grok](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/81710)*

> To understand intuitively or by empathy...

Expressing the lack of those is as simple as appending a *don't* or *can't*.